# Jmeter - how to use global CSV Data Set Config in Test Threads

Tags: jmeter

In one of my Jmeter scripts (5.11), I am trying to use one CSV file for inputs for all test threads defined.

[image]

But when I execute the scripts and check for the request body, it takes the first row for both thread groups. My assumption was, it takes one row for each iteration, like for local CSV Data Set Config, under thread group. Please sugges why it is happing so and how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set "Sharing Mode" to `All threads`, this way each thread will read next line on each iteration:

[image]

Demo (used [__threadGroupName()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadGroupName) and [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) functions for visualization):

[image]

More information: [CSV Data Set Config in Sharing Mode - Made Easy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/csv-data-set-config-in-sharing-mode-made-easy)

Comment: It worked. Thansk @Dmitri